# Does "Boost" module work together with "Theme Key" module?

Tags: caching, theming, theme-negotiation

I wonder if the [Boost](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost) module works together with the [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module.

Has anyone experience with both modules working together? Especially when it comes to different style-sheets for different devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two work well together ([Does ThemeKey supports Boost caching](https://drupal.org/node/1467816)) with the caveat:

> ThemeKey supports page caching and external caches like boost - if the
>   page is cachable.
>
> If you switch a theme depending on the user's browser, the page isn't
>   globally cachable at all, because other users are using different
>   browsers! That's not a ThemeKey issue.